# Leer ciertos elementos en una cadena

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supongamos que tengo esta cadena `a='12345&&&4554444'` como hago para leer solo los números de dicha cadena sin necesidad de hacerlo con un ciclo ya que la única forma que conozco es recorriendo la lista.

```
variable=str('')
for i in a:
    if i!='&':
         variable+=i
print(variable)
```

Cuya salida seria:

```
   1234545564444
```

Existe otra forma de hacer esto??

Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si solo tienes dígitos y "&" y quieres eliminar todos los caracteres "&" puedes usar `str.replace` simplemente:

```
a = '12345&&&4554444'
variable = a.replace("&", "")
print(variable)
```

Opciones más generales que funcionen independientemente de que caracteres tengas mezclados con los dígitos hay más, entre ellas:

- **Expresiones regulares:**

  ```
  import re

  a = '12345&&&4554444'
  variable = "".join(re.findall('\d+', a))
  print(variable)
  ```

  o usando `re.sub:`

  ```
  import re

  a = '12345&&&4554444'
  variable = re.sub("\D", "", a)
  print(variable)
  ```

  En este caso le indicamos que substituya por una cadena vacía (elimine) todo carácter que no sea un dígito (`\D`).
- **Usar un conjunto (`set`) con los caracteres permitidos para filtrar** los datos mediante un generador y un condicional aprovechando la eficiencia de las búsquedas en las tablas hash:

  ```
  a = '12345&&&4554444' 
  permitidos = set('0123456789')
  variable = "".join((c for c in a if c in permitidos))
  print(variable)
  ```
- **[`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)**, que retorna `True` si todos los caracteres de una cadena son dígitos:

  ```
  a = '12345&&&4554444'
  variable = "".join((c for c in a if c.isdigit()))
  print(variable)
  ```
- **[`str.tranlate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)**:

  ```
  import string


  class TransTable:
      def __init__(self, intab):
          self._trasntable = {ord(c): c for c in intab}

      def __getitem__(self, char):
          return self._trasntable.get(char)


  a = '12345&&&4554444'
  trans_table = TransTable(string.digits)
  variable = a.translate(trans_table)
  print(variable)
  ```

  `str.tranlate` recibe una "tabla" que tiene valores Unicode ordinales como índice  y que por cada uno retorna el valor por el que debe ser substituido. La "tabla" puede ser cualquier objeto que implemente el método `__getitem__`, como un diccionario. La clase `TransTable` se inicializa con una secuencia de caracteres que van a ser permitidos, cada vez que se llama a su método `__getitem__` este retorna el mismo carácter si está entre los permitidos o `None` en caso contrario (lo que implica que ese carácter es eliminado por `translate`).

Una observación, concatenar cadenas (`cad = "foo" + "bar"`) es especialmente ineficiente dado su carácter inmutable, lo que implica crear un nuevo objeto cada vez que se hace. `str.join` es mejor alternativa, sobretodo si se usa junto a un generador, ya que evitamos la construcción de objetos intermedios.

Tanto `str.tranlate`, las expresiones regulares y como usar un conjunto tienen la ventaja de poder de forma muy simple especificar que caracteres queremos que se mantengan en la cadena.

Comment: Gracias! no fui muy claro que puede tener mas de un elemento como & o ## o $, pero con este método es muy efectivo y rapido.

Comment: Tengo una duda amigo, para que es c.isdigit() ??

Comment: @David.O tanto str.isdigit como las expresiones regulares filtran cualquier carácter que no sea un dígito.  str.digits retorna True si todos los caracteres de una cadena son dígitos y False en caso contrario.

Comment: vale Gracias amigo

Answer (score 3):

Sí, hay varias formas, pero lo primero decir que a la hora de construir una cadena carácter a carácter, como haces tú con `variable`, el enfoque que sigues de ir concatenándole letras por el final con el operador `+=` es ineficiente debido a la forma en que python maneja las cadenas.

Ya que una cadena para python es inmutable, cuando le añades algo en realidad crea una cadena nueva copiando la anterior más lo que le hayas añadido. La cadena anterior se descarta. Esto repetido muchas veces implica copiar muchas veces la cadena, por lo que en su lugar suele usarse una lista, que sí que permite añadir cosas al final (con `.append()`) en lugar de copiar todo cada vez que añades algo.

Finalmente la lista resultante puedes convertirla en cadena con el operador `str.join()`

Ahora veamos diferentes formas de resolver el problema

### Usando listas

Básicamente tu código, pero cambiando la cadena `variable` por una lista:

```
a = '12345&&&4554444'
variable= []
for i in a:
    if i!='&':
         variable.append(i)
variable = "".join(variable)
print(variable)
```

### Comprensiones de lista (*list comprehensions*)

Puedes usar *list comprehensions* que es una característica propia del lenguaje python que premite sustituir bucles por una línea de código.
No sólo es más compacto, y en mi opinión más legible aunque eso va en gustos, sino también ligeramente más rápido:

```
a = '12345&&&4554444'
variable = [i for i in a if i!='&']
variable = "".join(variable)
print(variable)
```

### Programación funcional

Si vienes del mundo del Lisp o tienes una mente matemática, tal vez te interese el paradigma funcional, el cual también permite eliminar bucles cambiándolos por funciones que reciben como parámetros iterables y otras funciones e internamente aplican la función en cuestión a cada valor del iterable.

Esta modalidad no permite hacer nada que no se pueda hacer también con *list comprehensions* y de hecho el creador de Python prefiere las *comprehensions* con lo que las características funcionales de python (como `map()`, `filter()` y otras) han sido relegadas a un módulo aparte (`functools`) en lugar de ser parte del lenguaje como eran en la versión 2.

Pesonalmente encuentro más elegante la sintaxis de las *list comprehensions* pero va en gustos. Esta sería la modalidad funcional:

```
a = '12345&&&4554444'
variable = filter(lambda i: i!='&', a)
variable = "".join(variable)
print(variable)
```

En este caso `filter()` espera dos parámetros. El segundo es un iterable. El primero es una función que aplicará a cada elemento del iterable. Si la función retorna `true`, acepta el elemento. Si no lo rechaza. Lo que devuelve es otro iterable con los elementos aceptados (que después convierto en cadena con `"".join()`)

El primer parámetro que le paso a `filter()` es una *lambda*, que no es más que un tipo de funciones ultrasencillas cuyo código consiste tan sólo en una expresión cuya evaluación será el valor retornado. Se escriben poniendo la palabra `lambda`, el nombre del parámetro (en este caso `i`), dos puntos y el "cuerpo" de la función, que es la expresión a evaluar, cuyo resultado es lo que se retornará. No se puede poner en esta función ninguna sentencia de control. Tan sólo una expresión.

#### Funciones específicas de manejo de cadenas

Para sustituir sub-cadenas, extraer partes de las mismas que sigan un cietro patrón, "traducir" cada caráceter por otro diferente, etc. Python suministra muchos métodos en la clase `str`, y en el módulo `re` (expresiones regulares). No pongo aquí ejemplos porque ya los hay en otras respuestas.